# What is the proper syntax to include a telemetry field in the Custom Endpoint Synthetic Partition Key Template for route to CosmosDB from Azure iotHub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, telemetry

I have tried many options.

My Message Routing **Custom Endpoint** is set up in the Azure Portal.
I use a **partition key template** as follows:

`{deviceid}-{my_telemetry_date}`, so that I can achieve a partition key with the following example value:

> {"PartitionKey" : "FFFFFFFA-2023-10-22"}

where the `{"my_telemetry_date" : "2023-10-22"}`

**I have tried the following syntaxes:**

`{deviceid}-{Body.my_telemetry_date}`
but results in:

> {"PartitonKey" : "FFFFFFFA-{Body.my_telemetry_date}"}

`{deviceid}-{Body.<my_telemetry_date>}`
but results in:

> {"PartitonKey" : "FFFFFFFA-{Body.<my_telemetry_date>}"}

{deviceid}-{<my_telemetry_date>}
but results in:

> {"PartitonKey" : "FFFFFFFA-{<my_telemetry_date>}"}

`{deviceid}-<my_telemetry_date>`
but results in:

> {"PartitonKey" : "FFFFFFFA-<my_telemetry_date>"}

I need to append the Date contained in the telemetry data field my_telemtry_date onto the {deviceid}-

The {deviceid} is properly substituted, but cannot find any info on proper syntax to substitute a telemetry field's value in the Partition key template.

Comment: I cannot use `{deviceid}-{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD}`, as the date the telemetry data is actually synced to IotHub is used. My devices are often without internet connection, and sync at a later stage. Thus I need for the date stored in the **my_telemetry_date** field to be substituted.

Comment: could you please tell how to trying to achieve about. Through code ie : c#, pythonetc. If possible share your code.share the details How to sending and receiving the data with code or etc what type of code you used for storing and getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't include telemetry values in your partition key using the built-in features of IoT Hub. The partition key only allows certain values per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/message-endpoint/create?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=azure-cli-latest):

> The template for generating a synthetic partition key value for use with this Cosmos DB SQL Container. The template must include at least one of the following placeholders: {iothub}, {deviceid}, {DD}, {MM}, and {YYYY}. Any one placeholder may be specified at most once, but order and non-placeholder components are arbitrary. If partition key name is provided, partition key template defaults to {deviceid}-{YYYY}-{MM}.

If you need telemtry values to be part of the partition key, you will first need to route the message somewhere else (e.g. Azure Function) and from there pluck out the value and pass it to CosmosDB.

Comment: Hello Matthijs van der Veer
I suspected as much, but was hopeful that it just wasn't documented.
I don't wish to add the complexity of an Azure function, so resorted to adding my "synthetic" partition key to the actual telemetry data, and setting the CosmosDb container's partitionkey to `/Body.my_synthetic_partition_key_field`
Then I just disable the use of a synthetic partition key in the message endpoint.
I hope this is going to work as I envisage.
Is there a way to see on Azure that the partition key as set up is actually properly enforced?
Thank you so much.

Comment: I haven't used synthetic partition keys yet, so I'm afraid I don't know. I would love to hear your results though.